# How to dismiss previous view controller and move to next view controller in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

in my application i am using a UITableView as a navigation menu for my app, it has 5 cells, 'Home', 'Order Online', 'Gallery', 'Contact', 'About'.

how it works is, when the user clicks the menu button the UITableView Menu pops down and then when a cell is clicked the correct UIViewController is loaded.

Now, the problem is, the previous view controller that was presented (before i move to a new controller via the tableView menu) is not dismissed. so in the app i can present the 'order online' view controller multiple times which obviously causes a memory problem,

BUT i do not want the view controller to be dismissed when it presents the tableView as i am using a custom transition where the tableview slides down half way down the screen so a snapshot of the previous controller should still be present, only when a cell is clicked in the tableView and a new view controller is presented, should the view controller loaded before the tableView be dismissed.

here is a screenshot of storyboard :

[image]

here are some screenshots:

[image]

here is all the 'relevant' code from my TableViewController that is used as the navigation menu:

```
class MenuTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var menuItems = ["Home", "Order Online", "Gallery", "Contact Us", "About"]
var currentItem = "Home"


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! MenuTableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.titleLabel.text = menuItems[indexPath.row]
    cell.titleLabel.textColor = (menuItems[indexPath.row] == currentItem) ? UIColor.white : UIColor.gray

    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "homeView")
        self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    if (indexPath.row == 1) {

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "orderView")
        self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }

    if (indexPath.row == 2) {

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "galleryView")
        self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    if (indexPath.row == 3) {

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "contactView")
        self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    if (indexPath.row == 4) {

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "aboutView")
        self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
      let menuTableViewController = segue.source as! MenuTableViewController

      if menuTableViewController.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow != nil {


      }
  }
```

}

i have tried using

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

in a number of ways but it just doesn't make the app work the way i want it to, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: are you trying to create a side menu?

Comment: @Tj3n it is a slide down menu, i have added some screen shots in the question

Comment: let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                    if let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("loadingScreenVC") as? LoadingScreenNewsController{
                       
                        presentViewController(viewController, animated: false){
                            TourViewController().dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
                        }
                   
            } Try in this way

Comment: @AmritTiwari would i be able to dismiss the current view controller (menuTableViewController) and then present a view controller with that code? as with my app i can't say precisely which controller i need to dismiss as it can be any of the 5 controllers due to the content menu, so I'm thinking i will have to be able to dismiss the tableViewController and the ViewController Before that before presenting a new View Controller ?

Comment: yes, i have done this in my app. But you must know which controller you are gonna dismiss and present.

Comment: I have instantiated the view controller in the viewDidLoad() and used this code in the DidSelectRowAt `if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            
            self.present(homeController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            MenuTableViewController().dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }` but it seems like the dismiss code is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creating one, i suggest to use ONE custom navigation controller for the down menu + button, and it will control the content menu and vc, if you want to change it's root vc, just simply set vc of that custom navigation controller with `self.setViewControllers([vc], animated: true)`, other vc will automatically dismiss itself

Comment: ok, so in storyboard i should just have one navigation controller that controls a VC and the content menu (tableView)? and then programatically change its root VC when a cell is clicked in the content menu?

Comment: you should create your nav controller programmatically and set vc in code, that way you can control more aspect, dont even need to re create the menu view, including adding the menu button for default, in your storyboard just create all the screen and leave it there, im doing this way for my own side menu, and it should be similar, this way would require some of code change but you wont need to bother about presenting and memory when switching

Comment: Okay now i understand what you mean, i am still relatively in beginner-level in iOS development, is there any tutorial or resource that could point me in the right direction?

Comment: Sadly I dont have one, this is what i found it myself, but its not that hard as it sound, just subclass a nav controller and use it normally as normal nav controller in code, add a delegate to tell when it need to set new vc, add some function to control show/hide menu, and a property to hold that menu instance (the menu would be subview of it), this will separate your vc from the menu and navcontroller

Answer (score 2):

In you didSelectRowAt method, you are instantiating a new instance of the view controller every time you are to present the new controllers.

You could simply instantiate them beforehand (perhaps within viewDidLoad) within your menuTableViewController, then reuse the same instances of the controllers. Doing this will also allow you to be able to dismiss them from the menuTableViewController class as it is holding references to each of the new Controllers.

Comment: so would i do something like `var homeController : UIViewController` as a variable,  then in the viewDidLoad() i would have `let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        homeController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "homeView")` and then in the didSelectRowAt i can have `self.present(homeController, animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: i have done as you said, but still the app is using quite abit of memory and every time i reload the same viewController the memory usage gets higher, would i be able to do something like this in the DidSelectRowAt : `if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            
            self.present(homeController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            MenuTableViewController().dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            
            orderController.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
            galleryController.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
            }`

Comment: Is it possible that your view controllers are having some sort of strong circular reference that is causing the memory leak?

Comment: And yes, you can do something like that, although i'd recommend you to use a variable to contain the reference to the current view controller, so you can simply do something in `didSelectRowAt` to `self.present(newController, animated: true, completion: { [weak self] in self?.currentViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) self?.currentViewController = newController })`